# can i stream "webpage" from ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

**Hello everybody..**

just need to know if i can stream "webpage-html" via FFmpeg ,
i have script in my server , i used it to stream live poll into facebook, just need to know if i can stream any html or web page.

**this is my stream code:**

```
ffmpeg \
-re -y \
-loop 1 \
-f image2 \
-i images/stream.jpg \
-i /home/sounds/silence-loop.wav \
-acodec libfdk_aac \
-ac 1 \
-ar 44100 \
-b:a 128k \
-vcodec libx264 \
-pix_fmt yuv420p \
-vf scale=640:480 \
-r 30 \
-g 60 \
-f flv \
"rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/1270000000015267?ds=1&s_l=1&a=ATh1XXXXXXXXXXXuX"
```

Comment: Are you using php-ffmpeg or just ffmpeg via SSH?

Comment: i using php script throw ssh, the script using ffmpeg.. the script :  github.com/JamesTheHacker/Facebook-Live-Reactions

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using PHP GD or ImageMagik

Check out this git repo for an example of how to do it.

https://github.com/JamesTheHacker/Facebook-Live-Reactions

Comment: i used this git script , already.. but my question : how to stream webhtml page not image ?

Comment: @JohnSlovikara It's not made to render HTML. Another option is to use a pure HTML option. There is a dom-to-image JS plugin that will convert your page to an image.